# Cannot start exe from command code from apache as service

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I'm running apache as window service, having code as below to run NodeSetup.exe to add new device to SNMPc

```
$command = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SNMPc Network Manager\\NodeSetup.exe" -i -s:c -m:'.$mode.' -frct -uii -n:"' .$fileName. '" 2>&1';
$rts = exec($command);
```

SNMPc log said "Could connect to SNMPc console"

I did check log that the NodeSetup.exe had started background but another option as `-i -s:c -m:'.$mode.' -frct -uii -n:"' .$fileName. '" 2>&1` may not pass!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

According with the PHP documentation for [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function, you need escape all args and cmd with [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [escapeshellcmd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).

If your PHP file is encoded in UTF-8 and the concatened value too, you must be convert the $command string in the Windows local encoding.

For europe, you must convert UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 with [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding)